# extension components to get visit count in firefox's history and bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, gecko

I'd like to to know which interface can be used to get the visit count of each `link` in firefox's `bookmarks` and `history` for developing an extension

I've tried using `nav-history-service` to get the links for bookmarks and history but can't figure out how to view the visit count.

Comment: There's also this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code here will go through the first 10 bookmark entires. If it's a url it checks its `.accessCount` property which holds the number of times it was visited.

```
var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsINavHistoryService);

var query = hs.getNewQuery();
var options = hs.getNewQueryOptions();

// Query users bookmarks, not history
options.queryType = options.QUERY_TYPE_BOOKMARKS;
// Execute the search and store results
var result = hs.executeQuery(query, options);

// Open the root containerNode and open it
var resultContainerNode = result.root;
// OPEN resultContainerNode
resultContainerNode.containerOpen = true;
// Search results are now child items of this container?
for (var i = 0; i < resultContainerNode.childCount; ++i) {
    var childNode = resultContainerNode.getChild(i);
    if (childNode.type == childNode.RESULT_TYPE_URI) {
        console.log('childNode ' + i + ' is url = ', childNode)
        console.log('times visited = ', childNode.accessCount)
    }
    if (i >= 10) {
        break
    }
}

// CLOSE resultContainerNode
resultContainerNode.containerOpen = false;
```

gist is here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9729440