# How to move the contents(bookmarks, seperator, group) of Group to another Group

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, bookmarks

For reference:
[Add-on SDK -> Low-Level APIs -> places/bookmarks#Searching for bookmarks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#Searching_for_bookmarks)

How to move the contents(bookmarks, seperator, group) of Group to another Group, eg .:

UNSORTED -> Group1 -> **{bookmark1, separator1, bookmark2, groupIn1 ->{bookmarkIn1}, bookmark3}**

to:

TOOLBAR -> Group2 -> **here**

```
let { search, Bookmark, Group, save, remove, MENU, TOOLBAR, UNSORTED } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");    
search({ group: UNSORTED }).on('data', function (g) {
    console.log(g);
});
```

`g` returns each element separately, instead of an array.
What to do to first create an array?

Comment: I would explore this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22596715/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart ask about addons-sdk.

Comment: You can use this stuff from sdk, just do `require('chrome')`