# Firefox Addon bookmarks group (subfolder) search: discriminating between bookmarks and groups

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, bookmarks

I'm trying to make my first firefox addon.
For this I want to get all the groups directly under the TOOLBAR group.
I started [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#search%28queries.2C_options%29), but didn't manage to discriminate between groups and bookmarks.
Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
var { search, TOOLBAR } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");
search(
    { group: TOOLBAR, type: "group" },
    { sort: "title" }
).on("end", function (results) {
    var arrayLength = results.length;
    console.log(arrayLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        console.log(results[i]);
        //Do something
    }
});
```

I would be interested in how to do this using the linked API.
If this wouldn't work for some reason, I would also be interested in workarounds, older methods, more complicated or direct methods. In this case, please direct me to information that is roocky-proof :)

Comment: Nice work here. See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592343/extension-components-to-get-visit-count-in-firefoxs-history-and-bookmarks/22596715#22596715 see where I test `childNode.type == childNode.RESULT_TYPE_URI` that should be a bookmark. To see the other types do `console.info('childNode:', childNode)` then yo ucan see all that gets loged in browser console variable viewer.

Comment: Have you got your solution?

Comment: Thanks, still playing around with it a little bit.